# can we Increase Netty Server performance by using limiting thread pool

Tags: multithreading, netty

Can anybody help me to fix the correct thread pool size a according to the processor and RAM.

**Can we fix the limit of worker thread for better performance ?**

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to it.. All this depends on the workload etc. So you will not to attach a profiler to see how busy your worker threads are etc. The most important is that you need to make sure you have no blocking code in them. If you have you need an ExecutionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of I/O worker threads as a constructor parameter.  Do NOT use fixed thread pool executor.  Use an unbounded cached thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

```
  ChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
            new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(workerMax, 0, 0));
```

Check out [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor.html) for more details.